# Need to return all users with genre 'Acoustic'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Is there a better way to write this:

User.where(:genre_id => Genre.where(:name => 'Acoustic').first.id).first.first_name

Basically, I am trying to return all users with genre 'Acoustic'.

Above will work if there are users with the Acoustic setting. But if i do:

User.where(:genre_id => Genre.where(:name => 'Pop').first.id).first.first_name

I will get an error, since there are no users associated with the pop
genre...

Any suggestions to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a general way, many-to-many relationships really suck in mongo (the price you pay for has_one/has_many being so awesome)

I am assuming the problem is that `Genre.where(:name => 'Pop').first` returns nil? I would do this

```
User.where(:genre_id => g).first.first_name if g = Genre.where(:name => 'Pop').first.try(:id)
```

or if massive one line expressions aren't your thing

```
g = Genre.where(:name => 'Pop').first.try(:id)
if g
  User.where(:genre_id => g).first.first_name 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the usual nested `where` work?

```
User.where(:genre => { :name => 'Pop' })
```

Comment: Wont work, since genre is stored as a reference of BSON::ObjectId type

Answer (score 0):

You could try with find instead of where for Genre:

```
User.where(:genre_id => Genre.find(:first, :conditions => { :name => 'Pop' }))
```

This should work even when Genre.find returns nil.

Comment: User.where(:genre_id => Genre.find(:first, :conditions => { :name => 'Acousic' }).id).entries works. But User.where(:genre_id => Genre.find(:first, :conditions => { :name => 'Pop' }).id).entries returns RuntimeError: Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id since no user is associated with the pop genre yet...

Comment: As mentioned by Matt, using the try method could work as such: User.where(:genre_id => Genre.find(:first, :conditions => { :name => 'Pop' }).try(:id)).entries

Comment: Don't call .id on Genre.find(...) at all and it should work (at least works with Rails 3.0.1).

Comment: User.where(:genre_id => Genre.find(:first, :conditions => { :name => 'Acoustic' })).first_name returns BSON::InvalidDocument: Cannot serialize an object of class Genre into BSON.

Comment: Seems like mongodb doesn't play well with Rails queries, sorry for a wrong answer then=/